# Rails and Rake commands hang and do nothing at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't know why but when I run rake commands in my rails project, nothing happens. Also `rails server` does nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: `spring stop` was the answer for me this time around. If your projects uses spring...

Answer (score 2):

What fixed this for me was running

```
bin/spring stop
```

and then running my rake command after.

Answer (score 1):

you can add an "ruby -rtracer" to the begining to see where it is hanging.

Comment: For me, this helped expose errors that were previously being hidden.

Comment: I had to install the tracer gem with `gem install tracer` to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me entailed exiting rails console -sandbox.

I think sandboxing console puts a lock of some sort on the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the `--trace` argument to your rake calls to see if that sheds any light on where it is getting stuck. Failing that there may be some information in the logs.

It does suggest that something that is getting stuck during setting up your environment which may be something you've added to `environment.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using rvm?

A lot of advice these days is to install ruby within [rvm](https://rvm.io)  and rails within an rvm gemset. If you've done this, then you need to remember to do commands such as these at the start of your terminal session:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
rvm gemset use ruby193rails3
```

I found if I forgot to do this, then the rake command, even just a simple `rake --version` , would hang and thrash the disk.

...which all seems a bit fragile. I guess it's latching onto part of rails but with some files missing due to rvm not having moved them into place or something.

Comment: In my case, rails --version and ruby --version work fine.  But rake or rails commands which load the project-environment fail.  No disk-activity.  With "--trace" generates no output.  No logfile is created. Have to kill "-9" to stop it.  Commented out the env-file (development), but no change.    Other rails apps work fine, and a mirror-copy of this one works on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has a bug in Rails 4.1 which also causes this (not the OP's issue, based on date). For those googling, I solved this problem my typing "spring stop".  Spring will be automatically restarted the next time you run "rails ".  To give proper credit, I found this information from this blog:
http://www.dixis.com/?p=754